# Un-normalized lucene default similarity?

Tags: java, lucene

I am refactoring some old lucene code, and I found the following,

```
public class UnNormalizedLuceneSimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity {

    @Override
    public float lengthNorm(String fieldName, int numTerms) {
    if (numTerms > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    }
```

This code was using lucene version < 3.0

Now the method signature for lengthNorm has changed in the latest version of lucene.

```
lengthNorm(FieldInvertState state)
```

I cannot understand from the documentation how can I achieve the same un-normalized similarity with the new method.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FieldInvertState` has the method [getLength()](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/FieldInvertState.html#getLength()). By the looks of it, that method is all you need.

```
return state.getLength() > 0? 1 : 0;
```